# Use of the word bestow

Tags: grammar, register

If we see the language in its natural pace and flow which of the following sound better?
May God bestow sincerity upon me!
or
May God make me become sincere!
or
May I become sincere!

Comment: To **bestow sincerity** treats **sincerity** as though it were a gift, something that can be given. That would not be an invalid linguistic usage, but not everyone considers **sincerity** to be a gift let alone a divine gift; many regard it as a character trait.

Answer (score 1):

Your attempts to express a fervent wish differ in their degree of formality.  **bestow...upon** is more formal than **make me**.

If you're aiming for a "natural" expression, **make me become sincere** should be **make me sincere**.

> May God make me sincere!

or

> May God grant me sincerity!